# For events A and B it is known that: P(A' n B') = 0.35 and P(A) = 0.25 and P(B) = 0.6

Tags: probability

So I'm supposed to find (a) P(A n B) and (b) P(A|B).

By Venn Diagrams, I was able to figure out the following:
[image]

Now, unless this is wrong, the answer key I'm looking at is saying I should multiply P(A) and P(B), but that would only work if it's independent?

It says the (a) is 0.15 and (b) is 0.25

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly calculated $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = 0.2$ 
For $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$, use the law of conditional probability to obtain: 
$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{0.2}{0.6} = \frac{1}{3}$